# How can I pass on arrays from a form to a database with Sinatra and Datamapper?

Tags: mysql, arrays, forms, sinatra, datamapper

I've got stuck in the code below for several days. The task is to update multiple rows in a database table via a form in one page(maybe over a hundred rows). I've searched the web and learned how to use '[]' to get an array in form from this blog: http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/21/how-to-dynamically-add-form-elements-via-javascript/ , but my problem is I don't know how to pass on the arrays to my ruby code. Could anyone help me? Thanks!
Here is the main ruby file(main.rb):

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'data_mapper'

DataMapper.setup(:default, 'mysql://user:password@hostname/database')

class Check
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :answer, String
end

DataMapper.finalize.auto_upgrade!

get '/' do
  @checks = Check.all :order => :id.asc,  :limit => 5
  erb :home
end

put '/update' do
  n        = Check.get  params[:id1]
  n.answer = params[:answer1]
  n.save

  n        = Check.get  params[:id2]
  n.answer = params[:answer2]
  n.save

  n        = Check.get  params[:id3]
  n.answer = params[:answer3]
  n.save

  n        = Check.get  params[:id4]
  n.answer = params[:answer4]
  n.save

  n        = Check.get  params[:id5]
  n.answer = params[:answer5]
  n.save

  redirect '/'
end
```

Here's the embeded home.erb file which located in views directory:

```
<% i=0 %>
<form action="/update" method="post" id="edit">
  <% @checks.each do |check| %>
    <%= check.id %>
    <%  i = i + 1 %>
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
    <input type="hidden" name="id<%= i %>" value="<%= check.id %>" />
    <input type="text" name="answer<%= i %>" value="<%= check.answer %>" />
    <p>
  <% end %>
  <input type="submit" value="update"></p>
</form>
```

The array style home.erb maybe like this:

```
<form action="/update" method="post" id="edit">
  <% @checks.each do |check| %>
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
    <input type="hidden" name="myid[]" value="<%= check.id %>" />
    <input type="text" name="myanswer[]" value="<%= check.answer %>" />
    <p>
  <% end %>
  <input type="submit" value="update"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that you are looking at this the wrong way. You don't often see forms on web pages with hundreds of rows, so perhaps a rethink of your user interface might be in order -- to aid you and the user both.

Having said that, I think you can work with what you have got. You've done most of the work. Just change the route code so that it looks something like this?

```
put '/update' do
  i = 1
  while params["id#{i}".to_sym]
    id     = "id#{i}".to_sym
    answer = "answer#{i}".to_sym

    n        = Check.get params[id]
    n.answer = params[answer]
    n.save

    i += 1
  end

  redirect '/'
end
```

Instead of hard-coding `:id1`, `:answer1`, etc, we're now constructing them in a loop.  When `params[:id432]` or whatever is missing, the loop stops.

(Note: this isn't a terribly Ruby-ish way of solving the problem. I would probably use something shorter myself -- turning `params` into an array of hashes, maybe -- which you might, I think, have more problems understanding?)

Comment: Thanks Andy! It really works! In fact, I'm going to use the code in an exercise page which contains 100 problems in arithmetic. I think it's a simple way to do so.